# Finding Error, I am unable to locate it Help me out

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

i am un-able to locate that error in my code

> Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect
>   syntax near 'Name'.

```
try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserData_DB"].ConnectionString);

        string insert = "INSERT INTO UserData(First Name,Last Name,Father Name,CNIC NO,Gender,Religion,Address,City, Cell Number, Email) VALUES (@fName,@lName,@fathName,@cnicNo,@gender,@religion,@address,@city,@cellNumber,@email)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", TextBoxfName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", TextBoxlName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fathName", TextBoxFatherName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnicNo", TextBoxcnicNo.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@religion", RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxAddress.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellNumber", TextBoxCellNumber.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);

        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Column names cannot contain spaces! If you have columns with spaces in them (really bad idea to begin with), you **must use** square brackets around them: `INSERT INTO UserData([First Name], [Last Name], [Father Name], .....`

Comment: A column in sql shouldnt be named with two words. So either its first_name or firstName or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names in the insert have spaces and if the column names have spaces you need to surround them with square brackets [], like this:

```
INSERT INTO Names([First Name],[Last Name])VALUES('First Name 1','Last Name 1')
```

Ideally the column names in SQL shouldn't have spaces, I would recommend renaming them like `FirstName`,`LastName` e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

you must put attributs tha contain space in []

```
"INSERT INTO UserData([First Name],[Last Name],[Father Name],CNIC NO,Gender,Religion,Address,City, Cell Number, Email) VALUES (@fName,@lName,@fathName,@cnicNo,@gender,@religion,@address,@city,@cellNumber,@email)";
```